# Saving the state of a view after action executes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I was wondering how you would save the state of a view after it runs an action that leaves for another view then comes back?

Please Help

Comment: Is first view destroyed in process? If it's not, it should retain state. If it is destroyed, you can do it in several ways: archiving, NSUserDefaults, some class that tracks state, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Store state variables in NSUserDefaults or use NSArchive / sqlite database. Depends on what kind of state information you wish to store. Always assume your previous view will 'unload' if a new view is loaded (using presentModalView or the UINavigationController). This way you're always prepared for the worst. Under low memory conditions the view currently not visible gets its 'view' unloaded and thus you must recover your previous state yourself (you could even simply use class variables if the first view isn't destroyed).